# Suppose $F,G$ are adjoint functors with $\text{Hom}(FX,Y)\cong \text{Hom}(X,GY)$. If $\phi:FX\to Y$ surjection, what about $\phi':X\to GY$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose $F,G$ are adjoint functors with $\operatorname{Hom}(FX,Y)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(X,GY)$ where $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$ with $X\in\mathcal{C}$ and $Y\in\mathcal{D}$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ If $\phi:FX\to Y$ surjection or mono, can I conclude anything about mono or epi property of $\phi':X\to GY$ under identification of $\operatorname{Hom}(FX,Y)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(X,GY)$ by $\phi\to \phi'$? I have tried to see whether I can conclude mono or epi of $\phi'$. However, I can't conclude anything as I either have to modify domain or I can't test everything in the range part.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a classic adjoint: $G$ the forgetful functor from $\mathbf{Ab}$
to $\mathbf{Set}$, and $F$ the functor taking a set to the
free Abelian group on it.
Let $X$ be any nonempty set and $Y=FX$, the free group on $X$. If $\phi$
is the identity map on $FX$, it corresponds to the map $\phi':X\to FX$ taking
each $x\in X$ to the corresponding generator of $FX$. This $\phi'$
is certainly not a surjection.

Comment: Maybe you mean $Y=FX$ here. However, it seems for this case, mono holds. Does mono hold in general?